# Whats Select '1' for in the following stored proceedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
BEGIN    
 IF EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=@ID)      
  BEGIN     
    UPDATE Table1 SET Name=@Name  WHERE ID=@ID    
    SELECT '1'   
  END    
 ELSE     
  SELECT '0'    
END
```

Is this the row no. of the table or what ?
Also "IF EXISTS" is checking what ? the table or if the ID exists or not ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like whoever wrote that Stored Procedure is using that as a return value to indicate success or failure.

Doing things that way will result in a single row with a single column being returned for each call to the procedure.

The correct way to handle this would be to actually use the return value of the stored procedure, rather than returning the single column single row:

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FORM Table1 WHERE ID = @ID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Table1 SET Name = @Name WHERE ID = @ID
        RETURN 1
    END

    RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: so 1 and 0 are return values ?? Why " RETURN 1 " not used instead ?

Comment: @Happy Soul - I'm wondering the same thing. It could've easily been somebody who didn't know about RETURN.

Comment: SELECT '1' 's got 1 in single quotes so does this mean its a value only and not column no. or something?

Comment: @Happy Soul - That just means they're returning 1 as a string value instead of a number.

Comment: oh ok..so 1 is a string..hmmmm

Comment: I'd argue that the correct way would be **not** to use the return code and not to bother doing the existence check at all but simply do the update then check the rows affected passed back to the client application.

Comment: @Martin - If you want to indicate success/failure, why return more information than is necessary? Returning the Row Count has its purposes...but that clearly isn't what the original code is going for (the update statement could affect multiple rows depending on what the keys are and the sproc would always return 1).

Comment: @Justin. It's entirely possible that another concurrent transaction deletes the row between the existence check and the attempted update. Does that still count as "success"?

Comment: @Martin - I definitely wouldn't say the code was flawless (obviously). I was merely inferring intent from what code was already there.

Answer (score 3):

The IF EXISTS is checking if there is a row in Table1 with the given ID.  If there is a row it will update that row with the given name.  The Select "1" will return "1" and Select "0" returns "0".  The "1" or "0" would indicate if the row was found or not.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably some calling code checks this value to determine if a row was updated or not.

Rather than checking and updating (two table accesses) you might as well do this.

```
 UPDATE Table1 SET Name=@Name  WHERE ID=@ID    
 SELECT CASE WHEN @@Rowcount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

If `id` is the PK then you can just do

```
 UPDATE Table1 SET Name=@Name  WHERE ID=@ID    
 SELECT  @@Rowcount
```

Note as long as `SET NOCOUNT` is not on then the number of rows affected will get passed back to the client application anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Select '1' is used to indicate that Table1 contains the id value @ID (a parameter) was updated.  Select '0' indicates that Table1 does not contain the id value @ID.